# ZonedDateTime Serialize & Deserialize problem

Tags: spring-boot, camunda, zoneddatetime

I am facing an issue with the ZonedDateTime Serializer and Deserializer. It is happening on the POST and PUT Methods where another microservice is called through spring webclient.

```
ProcessInstanceWithVariables instance = processEngine
    .getRuntimeService()
    .createProcessInstanceByKey("MyKey")
    .setVariable("authorizedClient", authorizedClient)
    .setVariable("object", object)
    .executeWithVariablesInReturn();
```

The problem occurs on execution of the above and never reaches the webclient. On another note, if the request is directly sent to the microservice of target, it works totally fine but something clearly is happening at the Camunda level which is distorting the execution, resulting in a 400 error.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

---

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request from PUT http://localhost:8020/api/v1/endpoint  at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:179)  Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:  Error has been observed at the following site(s):   |_ checkpoint ⇢ 400 from PUT http://localhost:8020/api/v1/endpoint [DefaultWebClient] Stack trace:      at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:179)      at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientResponse.lambda$createException$1(DefaultClientResponse.java:206)      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:100)        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:92)        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121)        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:96)      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:287)         at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:330)        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1755)        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:152)        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136)        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:252)         at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:252)         at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136)        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:366)        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:367)        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:423)        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:607)      at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:96)         at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)         at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)         at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)       at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)         at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)         at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)         at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)       at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)         at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)       at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296)       at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)         at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)         at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)         at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)         at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)         at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)         at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)         at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)         at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)         at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)  Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99)        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1678)        at com.myproject.bpmn.camunda.delegate.MyDelegate.execute(MyDelegate.java:82)       at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.bpmn.delegate.JavaDelegateInvocation.invoke(JavaDelegateInvocation.java:40)      at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.delegate.DelegateInvocation.proceed(DelegateInvocation.java:58)      at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.delegate.DefaultDelegateInterceptor.handleInvocationInContext(DefaultDelegateInterceptor.java:92)        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.delegate.DefaultDelegateInterceptor.handleInvocation(DefaultDelegateInterceptor.java:63)         at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.ServiceTaskJavaDelegateActivityBehavior.execute(ServiceTaskJavaDelegateActivityBehavior.java:55)       at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.ServiceTaskJavaDelegateActivityBehavior.performExecution(ServiceTaskJavaDelegateActivityBehavior.java:44)      at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.TaskActivityBehavior.execute(TaskActivityBehavior.java:69)         at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.ClassDelegateActivityBehavior$1.call(ClassDelegateActivityBehavior.java:68)        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.ClassDelegateActivityBehavior$1.call(ClassDelegateActivityBehavior.java:65)        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.AbstractBpmnActivityBehavior.executeWithErrorPropagation(AbstractBpmnActivityBehavior.java:90)         at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.ClassDelegateActivityBehavior.execute(ClassDelegateActivityBehavior.java:65)       at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationActivityExecute$2.callback(PvmAtomicOperationActivityExecute.java:61)        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationActivityExecute$2.callback(PvmAtomicOperationActivityExecute.java:50)        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.PvmExecutionImpl.continueIfExecutionDoesNotAffectNextOperation(PvmExecutionImpl.java:2036)       at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationActivityExecute.execute(PvmAtomicOperationActivityExecute.java:42)       at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationActivityExecute.execute(PvmAtomicOperationActivityExecute.java:31)       at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.AtomicOperationInvocation.execute(AtomicOperationInvocation.java:99)         at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.invokeNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:131)       at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:111)      at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performOperation(CommandInvocationContext.java:86)      at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:628)        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:602)        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.PvmExecutionImpl$6.callback(PvmExecutionImpl.java:1975)      at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.PvmExecutionImpl$6.callback(PvmExecutionImpl.java:1972)      at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.PvmExecutionImpl.continueExecutionIfNotCanceled(PvmExecutionImpl.java:2042)      at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.PvmExecutionImpl.dispatchDelayedEventsAndPerformOperation(PvmExecutionImpl.java:1991)        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.PvmExecutionImpl.dispatchDelayedEventsAndPerformOperation(PvmExecutionImpl.java:1972)        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerStart.eventNotificationsCompleted(PvmAtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerStart.java:60)       at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerStart.eventNotificationsCompleted(PvmAtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerStart.java:30)       at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.core.operation.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:66)        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.AtomicOperationInvocation.execute(AtomicOperationInvocation.java:99)         at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.invokeNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:131)       at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:111)      at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performOperation(CommandInvocationContext.java:86)      at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performOperation(CommandInvocationContext.java:76)      at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:637)        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:612)        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.core.operation.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:62)        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.AtomicOperationInvocation.execute(AtomicOperationInvocation.java:99)         at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.invokeNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:131)       at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:111)      at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performOperation(CommandInvocationContext.java:86)      at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performOperation(CommandInvocationContext.java:76)      at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:637)        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:612)        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.core.operation.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:62)        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.AtomicOperationInvocation.execute(AtomicOperationInvocation.java:99)         at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.invokeNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:131)       at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:111)      at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performOperation(CommandInvocationContext.java:86)      at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performOperation(CommandInvocationContext.java:76)      at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:637)        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:612)        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.core.operation.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:62)        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.AtomicOperationInvocation.execute(AtomicOperationInvocation.java:99)         at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.invokeNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:131)       at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:111)      at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performOperation(CommandInvocationContext.java:86)      at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:628)        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:602)        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationTransitionCreateScope.scopeCreated(PvmAtomicOperationTransitionCreateScope.java:38)      at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationCreateScope.execute(PvmAtomicOperationCreateScope.java:54)       at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationCreateScope.execute(PvmAtomicOperationCreateScope.java:28)       at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.AtomicOperationInvocation.execute(AtomicOperationInvocation.java:99)         at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.invokeNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:131)       at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:118)      at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performOperation(CommandInvocationContext.java:86)      at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:628)        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:602)        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.PvmExecutionImpl.start(PvmExecutionImpl.java:287)        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.start(ExecutionEntity.java:458)       at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.PvmExecutionImpl.start(PvmExecutionImpl.java:263)        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.StartProcessInstanceCmd.execute(StartProcessInstanceCmd.java:66)         at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.StartProcessInstanceCmd.execute(StartProcessInstanceCmd.java:38)         at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:28)         at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:110)        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor$1.doInTransaction(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:46)       at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor.execute(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:44)         at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.execute(ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.java:70)       at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandCounterInterceptor.execute(CommandCounterInterceptor.java:35)         at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:33)       at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.ProcessInstantiationBuilderImpl.executeWithVariablesInReturn(ProcessInstantiationBuilderImpl.java:166)       at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.ProcessInstantiationBuilderImpl.executeWithVariablesInReturn(ProcessInstantiationBuilderImpl.java:137)       at com.myproject.bpmn.camunda.web.rest.v1.MyController.update(MyController.java:89)         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)      at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:920)        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)        at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92)       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)        at org.zalando.logbook.servlet.LogbookFilter.doFilter(LogbookFilter.java:71)        at org.zalando.logbook.servlet.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:31)      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)         at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)         at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)         at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)         at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter.java:146)      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)         at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)         at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)         at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)         at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:114)       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)         at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:160)      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)         at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)         at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)         at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)         at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)      at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)        at org.zalando.logbook.servlet.LogbookFilter.doFilter(LogbookFilter.java:71)        at org.zalando.logbook.servlet.SecureLogbookFilter.doFilter(SecureLogbookFilter.java:32)        at org.zalando.logbook.servlet.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:31)      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:109)      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)        at com.myproject.common.interceptor.GlobalWrapFilter.doFilter(GlobalWrapFilter.java:32)         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)         at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

2021-01-13 10:56:27.429 DEBUG 20780 --- [nio-7000-exec-1] org.camunda.bpm.engine.cmd               : ENGINE-13006 Finishing command -------------------- StartProcessInstanceCmd
---------------------- 2021-01-13 10:56:27.440 ERROR 20780 --- [nio-7000-exec-1] o.z.problem.spring.common.AdviceTraits   : Internal Server Error
```

Comment: `java.time.ZonedDateTime` has a very complex serialization behaviour and cannot really be recommended for serialization. Why not serializing just the `java.time.Instant` (or a combination of `LocalDateTime` and `ZoneId`) ? And about the 400-error, you should consult the error logs on the server in detail otherwise nobody can help you here.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option as the Camunda is interacting with existing microservices with that format. The issue happens are the inception level within Camunda because all http methods without ZonedDateTime as part of the object body deliver the result.

Answer (score 0):

Please check how serialized data is submitted to Camunda, e.g here:

https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.14/org/camunda/bpm/engine/variable/Variables.SerializationDataFormats.html

https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.14/user-guide/data-formats/data-formats-in-processes/

Comment: Thank you @rob2universe, I did follow these but unfortunately made no difference. The issue is at the inception where ZonedDateTime format is being passed on as part of the DTO body. The result of Post and Get without ZonedDateTime gets delivered just fine.

Comment: Can you share a stack trace?

Comment: I just updated the original question with the stack trace.